# how to validate a checkbox with multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have tried all i can to get a solution by googling, but couldnt get one.
i have the following php code which outputs a checkbox with multiple values, the values are from a database.

```
echo  '<input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" value="'.$courses["id_course"].'" course-credit="'.$courses["course_credit"].'" onclick="return course_credit();"/>  '.$courses["course_name"].';
```

when the check boxes are clicked, the javascript code inside course_credit() should run and adds up the course-credit values. i know how to go after that. but i am not sure how i can get the course-credit values.

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say that it "adds up the the course-credit values" and "i am not sure how i can get the course-credit values." Can you show the function and tell me what you want to do? You said you add up the values so you already have them, don't you?

Comment: i mean i want to get the course-credit value of the checked boxes and i want to add them all, so lets say every course has a 3 credit hour, when the user checks 3 checkboxes, the value will be 9. and i want to disable the remaining checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit based on comments below...** To make it work only on "ckeck" (not "uncheck").

This should work:

```
onclick="course_credit(this);"
```

In your function `course_credit()`, you'll get the value between the parenthesis.
So do something like:

```
function course_credit(obj){
    value = obj.value;

    if(obj.checked){
        credit = value*2;   // Seen in comment that you wanted it to double.
    }else{
        credit = 0;         // I dont know here... Set a default value for this case.
    }
    alert(value);
    // Rest of your code.
}
```

Comment: i tried to add every checked boxes value, but it only doubles the first checkbox value.    function course_credit(value)
{
   var credit = value;
   credit += value;
   alert(credit);   
      
}

Comment: You have to add it on every 'echo <input type="checkbox ...>'

Comment: Btw, to double the value, you could just do var credit=value*2;

Comment: thank you, but it's adding them even when unchecking.

Comment: Hew... Well sure, the event is onclick. Check or uncked is stil a click. Hold on, I'll edit about this.